# NHibernate fetchmany duplicated values repository pattern

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a problem with duplicated results in list for my query.

What I have is two `FetchMany` on a method for my repository:

```
    public IQueryable<MyEntity> Query()
    {
        return Session.Query<MyEntity>()
            .FetchMany(x => x.ListA)
            .FetchMany(x => x.ListB);
    }
```

Query:

```
var result = _myEntityRepository
    .Query()
    .Where(x => names.Contains(x.Name))
    .Where(x => x.ListA.Any(m => listAIds.Contains(m.Id)))
    .Where(x => x.ListB.Any(m => listBIds.Contains(m.Id)))
    .OrderBy(x => x.CreationDate)
    .ToList();
```

Mapping:

```
        HasManyToMany(x => x.ListA)
            .Table("MY_ENTITY_TYPE_A")
            .ParentKeyColumn("MYENTITY_ID")
            .ChildKeyColumn("MYENTITYA_ID")
            .Fetch.Join();
```

`ListA` is class MyEntityA with several properties.

`ListB` is class MyEntityB with several properties.

The SQL produced is good and gets the values I need, how ever the values added to `ListA` and `ListB` gets duplicated several times. ListA and ListB are seperate tables (many to many).

I use `fluent-nhibernate`.

I looked up using `ToFuture` but that only gave me `Method Not Implemented Exception` and I don't want to use NHibernate outside my repository.

Here is what I tried:

```
    public IQueryable<MyEntity> Query()
    {
        var query = Session.Query<MyEntity>();

        Session.Query<MyEntity>().FetchMany(x => x.ListA).ToFuture();
        Session.Query<MyEntity>().FetchMany(x => x.ListB).ToFuture();

        return query;
    }
```

Exception is thrown at:

```
        Session.Query<MyEntity>().FetchMany(x => x.ListA).ToFuture();
```

`TargetInvocationException` is thrown with inner exception "The method or operation is not implemented."

Stack trace:

```
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.ExecuteFutureQuery(NhLinqExpression nhLinqExpression, IQuery query, NhLinqExpression nhQuery)
   at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.ExecuteFuture(Expression expression)
   at NHibernate.Linq.LinqExtensionMethods.ToFuture[T](IQueryable`1 query)
```

How can accomplish this? At the moment I do `Disctint` on ListA and ListB, but it seems to be slower and not so nice with all the duplicated values in the entities created.

MyEntity has many items of EntityA in ListA and many items of EntityB in ListB, but there are no duplicates in the database.

Note: I have to use FetchMany for both, else there will be too many select queries!

Comment: One thing is not too clear to me: are you getting more than one `MyEntity` of same id or many duplicated `EntityA` and `EntityB` for each `MyEntity`?

Comment: Did you try once with a ResutTransformer? `IQuery.SetResultTransformer(New NHibernate.Transform.DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer())`

Comment: FYI, `Transformers.DistinctRootEntity` won't affect the contents of the `ListA` and `ListB` collections, it would just affect the number of root results, the instances of `MyEntity`, returned by the query.

Comment: I have updated the question with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting `ToFuture` to work will be important.  `x.ListA` X `x.ListB` is a Cartesian product.   `ToFuture` should work.  Can you provide more details on your attempt at using it?

Ignoring the Cartesian product, you can get your current approach to work by using `<set/>` instead of `<bag/>` when mapping `ListA` and `ListB`.  This tells NHibernate that the collections should not contain duplicates.  Normally this wouldn't be necessary, but including both `ListA` and `ListB` in the same query is creating the duplicate results.  `<set/>` should fix this.

Comment: I use fluent-hibernate and C#, so what are those types there? I use `List<MyEntityA> ListA`

Comment: Change `List<MyEntityA>` to `ISet<MyEntityA>` from the `Iesi.Collections.Generic` namespace, or just `ICollection<MyEntityA>` will do, too.  In the mappings, add `.AsSet()` to the `HasManyToMany`.